# iPhone app: How was Emoji programmed?

Tags: iphone

How was Emoji programmed?

I'm assuming the app downloads and installs a language pack in the core operating library? Then the app simply instructs the user how to enable multiple languages..

Comment: iOS 5.0 includes a a color Emoji font.  If you have a question about a specfic app's use of Emoji, you need to tell us which app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short - it isn't.

iOS always had emoji built in, but it was hidden by default on non-Japanese phones (I believe this may have changed in iOS 5.0). Emoji "installer" apps are just invoking some undocumented functionality in the OS which makes it start showing up.

Comment: Hi! Just curious... If they invoke undocumented functionality, how did they pass appstore review?

Comment: Usually by hiding it behind some other functionality. So, not in a good way. :)